# How to fix center of scroll in viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to develop zoom in/out function like [Canva](https://canva.com).

If I set height so height of element is larger than viewport, the center of scroll has to be fixed in place.

My react project uses input that type is range to change height value.

In this case, what should i do to fix center of scroll?

Code Here : [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-wildflower-irwb0)

Comment: JS fiddle and posted code is different

Comment: @RahulKumar Sorry, I uploaded other example by mistake. I fix it.